# $elemMatch filter for nested array using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the JSON

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "productList": {
    "count": 25,
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 403492,
        "description": null,
        "plans": [
          {
            "name": "test1",
            "type": "G"
          },
          {
            "name": "test2",
            "type": "Y"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

And i want to get plans for just type of "G" i dont want to test2 back to the json 
I tried to use $elemMatch but not working

```
Document query = new Document();

query.append("plans", new Document().append("$elemMatch", value));
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's clear **[$elemMatch(query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)** is a query method to fetch data when a element of an array match with query!

What you want is **[$elemMatch(projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** ! But there is a problem on this projection according to the [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) :

> Both the **$** operator and the **$elemMatch** operator project the first
>   matching element from an array based on a condition.

that means you will just get the first element matched with query , 
so maybe it's not match your need !

there is 2 way :

1- to project data you want in you application side , maybe using java stream api!

2- using **[$filter(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)**

second way (java code):

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.match;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.project;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(
            "mongodb://localhost:27017"
    );

    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("TEST");
    MongoCollection<Document> documentMongoCollection =
            database.getCollection("test");

    Document document = documentMongoCollection.aggregate(
            Arrays.asList(
                    match(elemMatch("productionList.products.plans" , eq("type" ,"G")))

                    ,project(new Document("productionList.products" ,
                            map("productionList.products" , "this" ,
                                    new Document("plans" ,
                                            filter("$this.plans" ,
                                                    "plan" ,
                                                    new Document(
                                                            "$eq" ,
                                                            Arrays.asList("$$plan.type" , "G")
                                                    )))
                                            .append("description" , "$$this.description")//make it present
                                            .append("id" , "$$this.id"))) //make it present
                            .append("responseCode" , 1) //include
                            .append("productionList.count" , 1) //include
            )
    )).first();



    System.out.println(document.toJson());
}


private final static Bson filter(String arrayName , String as , Bson cond)
{
    //so to do it !

    Document document = new Document("input" , "$"+arrayName);

    if(as!=null && !as.isEmpty())
        document.append("as" , as);

    document.append("cond" , cond);

    return new Document("$filter" , document);
}

private final static Bson map(String arrayName ,String as , Bson in)
{
    Document document = new Document("input" , "$"+arrayName);

    if(as!=null && !as.isEmpty())
        document.append("as" , as);

    document.append("in" , in);

    return new Document("$map" , document);
}
}
```

maybe its hard to understand what I wrote on this code , you need to check following links :

[$map(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

[$project(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Answer (score 0):

The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) projection operator cannot be used with nested arrays of 2 levels. The way to get the matching array element from the 2nd level of the nested array is by using an [Aggregation Pipleline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html) as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $unwind: "$productList.products" },
  { $unwind: "$productList.products.plans" },
  { $match: { "productList.products.plans.type": "G" } },
] )
```

This translates to the following **Java** code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost/");
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection");

List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
                        unwind("$productList.products"), 
                        unwind("$productList.products.plans"), 
                        match(eq("productList.products.plans.type", "G"))
                      );                                    
List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(results);   
results.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

Comment: Unwind can not meet his need . As he said he wana fetch the same json structure !